# При замене фрагмента приложение сворачивается

Tags: java, android

При выборе второго пункта в `Navigation Drawer` приложение просто сворачивается и остается прошлый фрагмент. Фрагменты точно нужны для того, чтобы менять контент при выборе в `Navigation Drawer`?

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fr = null;
    if (id == R.id.nav_store) {
        fr = null;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_plus) {
        fr = new psplus();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_people) {
        fr = null;
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.nav_view, fr)
            .commit();
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Никаких синтаксических ошибок нет, все классы есть в проекте. Что происходит?

Comment: У тебя в коде: .replace(R.id.nav_view, fr) - первый аргумент метода replace - это контейнер куда ты хочешь поместить фрагмент. R.id.nav_view - это сома шторка. Я думаю ты хочешь куда то в другое место его поместить. И что за прошлый фрагмент? У тебя он только один вроде, как раз второй - fr = new psplus();

Comment: Я хочу поместить фрагмент psplus в то место, где сейчас находится фрагмент nav_view